# Save image without rescaling

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a 2D array and I need to save it as an image. What's the best way to do it without rescaling? I want to read the image afterwards and check that the values have been saved correctly. I am saving it as a bmp so to avoid compression issues, but other formats should also be fine.

Comment: PNG works (compressed, lossless).

Comment: @Cloud, It doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save an image you can use SciPys [`imsave`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html) function.

```
imsave(path, image)
```

EDIT: To Save an image as `bmp` just choose the file extension in `path` accordingly.

EDIT2: To prevent intensity normalization you can use

```
scipy.toimage(image, cmin=0, cmax=255, mode='I').save("image.png")
```

You can use `mode'I'`to save your image in a specific format. Just be sure that your input is of type `uint16`.

Comment: `imsave(path, image)` does not work; I am using `scipy.misc.imsave(path, image)` instead. When I compare data obtained reading the image with the original data, I have that the do not coincide... are you aware of any saving procedure that could explain that?

Comment: Do you save your image as a bmp? In what way do they differ?

Comment: It seems like scipy does some range normalization. You can use `scipy.toimage(image, cmin=0, cmax=255).save("image.png")` to prevent that

Comment: In this way the maximum value is rescaled to 255, right? What if I want to save values higher than that without rescaling?

Comment: Just choose the scales according to your needs.

Comment: Perfect. And is there a way to save in 16 bits? Something like `scipy.toimage(image, cmin=0, cmax=255).save("image.png").astype(np.uint16)`

Comment: I edited my answer. You can use `mode='I'` in `scipy.toimage` to save a `uint16` Matrix as 16 Bit image.

Comment: Well, this answer is from 2013 and still valid for older scipy Versions so I will not change it. For replacement in new Versions see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57545125/2927205