# ImportError with scipy.misc cannot import toimage

Tags: python, scipy

I tried making some Perlin noise but with
`from scipy.misc import toimage`

I get an ImportError:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Perlintest.py", line 3, in <module> from scipy.misc import toimage ImportError: cannot import name 'toimage' from 'scipy.misc' (C:\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'toimage'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545125/attributeerror-module-scipy-misc-has-no-attribute-toimage)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scipy.misc.toimage` is removed since version 1.2, [link to documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.toimage.html). As the documentation suggests.

> Use Pillow’s Image.fromarray directly instead

It's somewhat confusing if you're a new user. So, explaining a bit. It expects you already have Pillow installed. If not first `pip install numpy scipy` first and then `pip install Pillow`.

Example code from the official Pillow `Image.fromarray` [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray)

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
im = Image.open('image.jpg')
a = np.asarray(im)
im = Image.fromarray(a)
```

Otherwise, use an [older version](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/0.19.1/) of `scipy`.

For any above I recommend generating `requirements.txt` or if you use conda then `env.yml` for your project dependencies and future use of your project without their versioning and import errors.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the below

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = Image.open('name.jpg')
plt.imshow(img)
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing

```
from scipy.misc import toimage
```

to:

```
from scipy.misc.pilutil import toimage
```