# Which attribute in Scipy version 1.6.1 is compatible with the scipy.misc.toimage by scipy version 1.0.0?

Tags: python, scipy, opencv

Once I use `scipy.misc.toimage` with scipy version 1.6.1, it always error with `AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'toimage'`

Regarding the documentation, the attribute like `toimage` would be used for `scipy.misc` just only version 1.0.0 until before version 1.2.0

Source: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/misc.html

Currently, I use python 3.8 and may I know which attribute in scipy version 1.6.1 have the same functional as `scipy.misc.toimage` from scipy version 1.0.0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'toimage'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545125/attributeerror-module-scipy-misc-has-no-attribute-toimage)

Answer (score 1):

The linked documentation, [section `toimage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.toimage.html#scipy.misc.toimage) states it explicitly:

> Use Pillow’s Image.fromarray directly instead.

Install the `Pillow` package (if not installed already), then use e.g.

```
from PIL import Image
Image.fromarray(data)
```

(where `data` is a NumPy array.)